# Content Security frame-ancestors not working as expected

Tags: node.js, express, iframe, helmet.js

I have a react app running on http://localhost:5000/. Also I have another web app running on http://127.0.0.1:1880 and I want to open this website in iframe from react app. I set Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors http://localhost:5000/ but I'm still getting cors error and unable to see the content in iframe.
Node js code where I set the policies:

```
app.use(cors())
app.use(helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
        // "child-src": "http://localhost:5000",
        directives:{
            frameAncestors: "http://localhost:5000/",
        }
    }
  }));
app.use(helmet.crossOriginEmbedderPolicy({ policy: "credentialless" }));
app.use(helmet.crossOriginOpenerPolicy({ policy: "unsafe-none" }));
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
```

[image: ss]

Is there any way to fix this issue?

[image: cors]

Comment: What CORS error?

Comment: It's hard to tell without the error, but you may wish to disable the `X-Frame-Options` header. In Helmet, this is done by setting `frameguard` to `false`.

Comment: It wasn't giving any error in console. I was only seeing it in network tab. I cleaned browser cache restart both app and my computer. Now it's fixed, thank you